# jQuery undo click() function changes

Tags: jquery, click

I want to make some changes to the css and class on form input text fields, when users click the reply button and I got it working but then the form at the bottom stays with the changes. 
So my question: Is  there any way to undo these changes and return the form to previous state ?

```
$(".comment-reply-link").click(function() {
    if($("#commentform").width() < 590){
        $("#commentform input[type='text']").css("margin-left","0");
        $("#commentform input[type='text']").removeAttr('class');
    }
})
```

Comment: You can use the same code to reset the values back to their previous values under whatever event you need.

Comment: You can use setTimeout() to restore automatically after "reply" button is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, There is no method available to store changes happened in the DOM and revert back when you want. You can achieve that like below

```
 $('.element').bind('click', plus10);
 $('.revertChange').bind('click', minus10);
 var input = $('#someInput');

 function plus10(){ 
      input.val(input.val() * 1 + 10); 
 }
 function minus10(){ 
      input.val(input.val() * 1 - 10); 
 }
```

If you are trying to add styles and revert make a class with necessary styles then toggle class

```
 .someClass{
      margin:10px;
      color:green;
      /* ...... */
 }
```

then toggle class on element like below

```
 $('element').toggleClass( "someClass" );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to undo the inline styles, well yes you can :

```
$("#commentform input[type='text']").css("margin-left","");
```

This will for example reset/undo your inline style of `margin-left`.

Comment: yes but how to trigger that event do I have to make another click function for eg. when they click submit or cancel button to do these changes?

Comment: @JetonRamadani Well, when do you want to have it resetted? It's unclear what you mean with "form at the bottom". Provide me with a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so i can see your problem.

Comment: Sorry my bad, each comment has a reply button next to it, when clicked the form comes up and I did those changes up. Now the form has the option to cancel or submit the comment. So can i do another click() on these buttons to reset those changes @nkmol

Comment: This sounds to a quick fix of the css to me. Are you sure you need the css manipulation when clicked the reply button? I really suggest to make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) then i might see the underlaying problem you're having.

Comment: @JetonRamadani, use only css for this. When the comment form is appended to a comment apply other styles. For example if the comments has the class `.comment`, you can overide the css with `.comment #commentform input[type='text']`.

Comment: @Smartik wow man you just saved me! It was right there the class and I didn't see it  lol. Thank you for this comment!

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach to store a cloned state with jquery's data and restore it whenever you want. Regardless of the number of changes you make to the element.
For example,

http://jsfiddle.net/xr63r/

**HTML**

```
<div id="commentform">
    <input type="text" class="red-border" />
    <button class="comment-reply-link">test</button>
</div>
<button class="undo">undo</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(".comment-reply-link").click(function() {
    if($("#commentform").width() < 590){
        /*create a clone of the element you modify*/
        var theClone = $("#commentform").clone(true,true);
        /*add the cloned element to a data attribute for restoring the state*/
        $("#commentform").data("undo",theClone);

        /*any kind of css modifications may follow*/
        $("#commentform input[type='text']").css("margin-left","0");
        $("#commentform input[type='text']").removeAttr('class');
    }
})

$(".undo").click(function(){
/*if state undo exists, restore it*/
    if($("#commentform").data("undo")){
        var theClone = $("#commentform").data("undo");
        $("#commentform").replaceWith(theClone);
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
/*this is an example css style related to a class*/
input.red-border{
    border:red 1px solid;
}
```